QGIS: extracting desired range values from a raster
In QGIS, I've successfully extracted a rainfall range from GeoTIFF file using raster calculator and the range displays. However, the extraction is still showing values below the minimum value of 90mm. How do I effectively clip/mask out the values outside the desired range? I would like to polygonise this extraction without showing all the values!

Could you share the settings you used by providing a screenshot? Your question is too vague.

Formula as follows: ("wc2.0_bio_30s_01@1" >= 90 AND "wc2.0_bio_30s_01@1" >= 120) * "wc2.0_bio_30s_01@1"

I am not sure how to add screen shot here...

Warp the output to set "NoData value for output bands" to 0
